# Gloox XMPP library, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, xcode, xmpp

I'm attempting to code a basic XMPP client with the gloox C++ library. It's my first time using C++ but gloox sounded the most appropriate for my needs and I've got both C and OO experience so I wasn't too worried about trying it.

I have however run into a wall from the start. I can't even get a "hello world" out of my code, instead getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (using Xcode 4).

http://pastebin.com/7vS6ExUV

Here's the code, it crashes on line 35. Gloox mailing list is pretty quite so I thought I'd ask here. Bit worrying there is no gloox tag though!

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used gloox (or C++ I'm happy to say). I don't see anything wrong with your code at a glance. If you fail to get anywhere with gloox though, try Swiften. It's a newer, but more active, library being driven by development of an actual client.

Comment: This was the route I ended up going thanks to you. Seems it was a wise choice! To others considering, i suggest this library, though it is a royal pain in the arse to compile. Swiften has good support as Matt says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little rusty on the old C++ myself, but your main method doesn't look right to me.  On line 49 you declare a pointer to an instance of MyClass, but don't allocate it.  So you're calling doIt() on at best a null pointer, at worst an garbage object in some random memory space.

Either create a new instance or just drop the pointer.  e.g.:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
   MyClass a; // note, no pointer
   a->doIt();
   return 0;
}
```